# Passing an argument to a slot

Tags: qt, qsignalmapper, qt-slot

I want to override mouseReleaseEvent with a bunch of QActions and QMenus...

```
connect(action1, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onStepIncreased()));

connect(action5, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onStepIncreased()));

connect(action10, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onStepIncreased()));

connect(action25, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onStepIncreased()));

connect(action50, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onStepIncreased()));
```

So I want to pass an argument to the slot `onStepIncreased` (as you can imagine they are 1,5,10,25,50). Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: Instead of passing parameters, consider analyzing sender() inside the signal.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html). Like this:

```
QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;
connect (action1, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
connect (action5, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
connect (action10, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
connect (action25, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
connect (action50, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;

signalMapper -> setMapping (action1, 1) ;
signalMapper -> setMapping (action5, 5) ;
signalMapper -> setMapping (action10, 10) ;
signalMapper -> setMapping (action25, 25) ;
signalMapper -> setMapping (action50, 50) ;

connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(onStepIncreased(int))) ;
```

Comment: I still remember times, when Qt didn't have QSignalMapper, and the only solution was setting property on objects connected to same slot and using sender()->property(...)

Comment: @Kamil Klimek You didn't have to; you could have written your own mapper :)

Comment: How to use this if my `context` parameter targets a to a class which has no acess to the actions? so eitherway, the `context` signalmapper wouldn't have access to the actions, or if I'd have the signalmapper into the same class, would be the wrong context for the conecting slots.

Comment: Worth noting (2018, Qt5, C++11) that QSignalMapper is deprecated.  From the link: "This class is obsolete. It is provided to keep old source code working. We strongly advise against using it in new code." The answer by @kuba, below, is now a better one.

Answer (score 151):

With Qt 5 and a C++11 compiler, the idiomatic way to do such things is to give a functor to `connect`:

```
connect(action1,  &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(1); });
connect(action5,  &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(5); });
connect(action10, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(10); });
connect(action25, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(25); });
connect(action50, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(50); });
```

The third argument to `connect` is nominally optional. It is used to set up the thread context in which the functor will execute. It is always necessary when the functor uses a `QObject` instance. If the functor uses multiple `QObject` instances, they should have some common parent that manages their lifetime and the functor should refer to that parent, or it should be ensured that the objects will outlive the functor.

On Windows, this works in MSVC2012 & newer.

Comment: This combination of C++11 lambdas and Qt 5's ability to connect a functor to a signal is such a useful and yet underrated feature.

Comment: I adapted this solution to my case. However, it throws an error if I use `SIGNAL(triggered(bool))` instead of `&QAction::triggered`. Can somebody please explain to me why?

Comment: It doesn't "throw" an error. The compiler complains, and the error message should tell you why: there's no `QObject::connect` overload that takes a `const char *` as the 2nd argument and a functor as the third or fourth argument. The Qt4-style `connect` syntax doesn't mix with the new syntax. If you wish to use the old syntax, you forfeit the ease of connecting to functors (even though it could be approximated if you had a C++11 compiler but used Qt 4).

Answer (score 14):

The [`QObject::sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) function returns a pointer to the object that has signaled to the slot. You could use this to find out which action was triggered

Comment: I beg your pardon? The slot is a member of a subclass of QObject, thus it has also a QObject::sender() member. Just call sender(), and you will be given a QObject* pointing to your action. After that you can use objectName() or property() of an acquired action to collect more information. You can also convert it to an action object if you really want to, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::bind` This is a functional object adapter that allows functional objects to be adaptee to a given number of parameters.

For example, you create your own chat server. That contains two classes: ChatServer and ServerWorker.

ChatServer is QTcpServer class and ServerWorker is QTcpSocket ( manage the socket on the server side).

Signals in ServerWorker header:

```
void error();
```

In your ChatServer header you define these private slots:

```
void userError(ServerWorker *sender);
```

In cpp file you create these object and in `incomingConnection` method that run after socket connect, you connect slots and signals using `std::bind`:

```
void ChatServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    //some code
    connect(worker, &ServerWorker::error, this, std::bind(&ChatServer::userError, this, worker));
}
```

`std::bind` creates a functor with some fixed arguments. For example `connect(worker, &ServerWorker::error, this, std::bind(&ChatServer::userError, this, worker));` will result in `this->userError(worker)`;  to be called every time the worker emits the error signal.

`userErrorslot` is executed every time a socket connected to a client encounters an error. It has signature:

```
void ChatServer::userError(ServerWorker *sender)
{
    //some code
}
```

[Example](https://github.com/VSRonin/ChatExample/blob/commonlib/QtSimpleChat.pro)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can subclass QAction with an m_increase member variable.
Connect the triggered() signal to a slot on your new QAction subclass and emit a new signal (e.g. triggered(int number)) with the correct parameter.
e.g.

```
class MyAction:public QAction  
{  
public:  
    MyAction(int increase, ...)  
        :QAction(...), m_increase(increase)
    {  
        connect(this, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onTriggered()));  
    }  
protected Q_SLOTS:  
    void onTriggered()  
    {  
        emit triggered(m_increase);  
    }  

Q_SIGNALS:
    void triggered(int increase);   

private:  
    int m_increase;  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QVector<QAction*> W(100);
 W[1]= action1;
 W[5]= action5;
 W[10]= action10;
 W[25]= action25;
 W[50]= action50;

for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
  QSignalMapper* signalmapper = new QSignalMapper();
  connect (W[i], SIGNAL(triggered()), signalmapper, SLOT(map())) ;
  signalmapper ->setMapping (W[i], i);
  connect (signalmapper , SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(onStepIncreased(int)));
}
```