# How to get calling button from a clicked event

Tags: qt, signals-slots, pyside, multiplexing

I'm trying to make an small gui to deploy .ear and .war files on my
local glassfish installation. SO i have made five rows containing a
file name field, a checkbox and a button to bring up a file dialogbox
to locate the war/ear file. It would be nice to have all buttons call
the same function and from the function sort out which of the five
buttons who made the call ( to update the correct text fields ). Don't
know if this is the intended way of doing it in an object oriented way
but my only gui programming experience is some old win16 event
loops :).

//BRG Anders Olme

Comment: Most Pyside questions are Qt ones too. If you want to get answers more quickly consider tagging your questions with Qt tag. It's especially true for Pyside which is much younger than PyQt and thus  less known.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153157/passing-an-argument-to-a-slot/5153522#5153522. Instead of `int`, you will probably want to use `QString`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Connect each button's `click()` signal with one and the same slot and use [`QObject * QObject::sender () const [protected]`](http://qt-project.org/doc/latest/QObject.html#sender) in this slot to find out which button sent the signal (was clicked). Alternatively you could use [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/latest/QSignalMapper.html) which is a special class made just for this kind of task.

Answer (score 10):

```
QPushButton *buttonA = new QPushButton("A");
QPushButton *buttonB = new QPushButton("B");
QPushButton *buttonC = new QPushButton("C");

buttonA->setObjectName("A");
buttonB->setObjectName("B");
buttonC->setObjectName("C");

connect(buttonA, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testSlot()));
connect(buttonB, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testSlot()));
connect(buttonC, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testSlot()));

//Now in slot implementation
void QWidget::testSlot()
{
  QObject *senderObj = sender(); // This will give Sender object
  // This will give obejct name for above it will give "A", "B", "C"
  QString senderObjName = senderObj->objectName(); 

  if(senderObjName == "A")
  {
   //Implement Button A Specific 
  }
  //Similarly for "B" and "C"
  if(senderObjName == "B")
  {
   //Implement Button B Specific 
  }
  if(senderObjName == "C")
  {
   //Implement Button C Specific 
  }
}
```

I have used this method to implement such case because code is more readable but it may be time consuming as String comparison comes.
Thank you!