# Qt SLOTS parameters (Beginner)

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

I'm a beginner to Qt and am making (or at least trying to make) a basic calculator.  If I understand correctly, when doing this:

```
connect(my_button_4, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(writeNumberLbl("4")));
```

The "4" is not accessible (rather, only its type is) in writeNumberLbl.  Basically, I would like so that when the button is clicked, the label sets its text to "4".  However, I have the numbers 0 to 9, so I wanted to do:

```
connect(my_button_0, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(writeNumberLbl("0")));
connect(my_button_1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(writeNumberLbl("1")));
...
connect(my_button_9, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(writeNumberLbl("9")));
```

My writeNumberLbl function is:

```
void Calculator::preWriteVal(QChar val)
{
    QString curVal = ui.lbl_output->text();
    curVal += val;
    ui.lbl_output->setText(curVal);
}
```

However, I can see that this will not work due to the parameter, 'val'.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?  Thank you.  I did look to see if this question had already been answered and couldn't find anything.  If it has, please provide me a link.

Also, is it possible, using Qt Designer 4, to connect a widget to a custom slot?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a similar question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153157/passing-an-argument-to-a-slot/5153522#5153522

Comment: You can follow my blog for newbies of Qt application development: https://qtnoobies.blogspot.my/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,Qt's signal/slot system requires that the number of parameters of signal function is not **less than** that of slots function.
In your example,the signal function click() have zero parameters and slot function  writeNumberLbl("4") have one parameter,this will not be accepted by the Qt's signal/slot system and if you run your program in debug mode of Qt creator,the qDebug will show you a message like 'Incompatiable signal/slot' blalbalba~. To solve this problem, just read  the article given by Arnold Spence. It is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to tackle this problem and they are outlined [very nicely here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html). Although that page is a bit old, I think it is still quite valid. I would recommend using a signal mapper.

For your second question, yes. You can connect signals and slots using Qt Designer by setting the designer in "Edit Signals/Slots" mode. Once in this mode, for example, you can drag a connection line from a button to the form. A dialog will open up allowing you to choose the signal and slot to connect. If you haven't already implemented a slot in code, you can specify the name of a slot and then add the code for it afterward.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; however, I'm aware of the "Edit Signals/Slots" mode, I guess what I was wondering was whether there is some way to drag, say, a pushbutton to a custom slot (a slot that I've made).

Comment: Yes. If you have already defined a slot, you can drag a connector to the object that has the slot and wire them up in the resulting dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think that I understand much better now.

In the document it says this towards the end: "...if you were to implement a palette tool allowing the user to choose a color from a set of standard colors and needed to emit a colorSelected(const QColor &) signal, your best bet would be to use the sender() approach or the subclass approach described above."

I was wondering if I would need a if-else statements to say, for instance:
if(button1 == (*pusbutton) sender())
// change palette colour to blue
else if(button2 == (*pusbutton) sender())
// change palette colour red
etc.

Answer (score 0):

The number of parameters in Slot can not exit those in Signal? and pressed() has none. You have two choices (three, counting the dumb one):

1. Use QSignalMapper. Its help is self-explanatory.
2. Connect all your buttons to single slot. In it, find out what button has been pressed. QObject::sender() function helps.

There are even more ways, but more complicated.