# Detect QMenu caller when using same SLOT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMenu and actions added to it. Works fine. Assume it does have menu called **"Paste here"** in it.

So now I have 3 buttons, I assign this same menu to three buttons:

```
btnNum1->setMenu(MyMenu);
btnNum2->setMenu(MyMenu);
btnNum3->setMenu(MyMenu);
```

Now in the triggered slot, when I do:

```
qDebug() << QObject::sender();
```

I get the `QAction` which is the submenu item, I want to know which button invoked the menu which then user clicked on a menu item and triggered the slot. I need to know is it menu loaded in `btnNum1` or `btnNum2` or `btnNum3`.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think so.  You'll probably need to create three different menu objects if you want to be able to distinguish them.

Comment: Take a look at the right answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153157/passing-an-argument-to-a-slot) question.

Comment: As @folibis links, you can solve this easily via ``QSignalMapper``

Comment: @folibis, how to you define same action for two different buttons with same menu? I can't see how with SignalMapper

Comment: yes, you are right @JohnMcKean. You need to track what button cause to menu popup, not action. So maybe you have to redefine `QPushButton` or `QMenu` to set suitable pointer to button while button pressing. And so you will be able to get this pointer from `QAction->menu()->myPointerToButton`