# Qt - "No such slot", although there is

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to connect a button to a function, so when I push the button, the function gets called with a specific parameter. I have

```
class FieldGridWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    FieldGridWidget(QWidget *parent=0);
    ~FieldGridWidget();

public slots:
    void resizeGrid(int n);

private:
    QGridLayout* _gridLayout;
    QVector<QPushButton*> _buttonGrid;

};
```

then the button

```
_button3 = new QPushButton("3x3", this);
```

and I'm trying to connect it so if clicked, the `resizeGrid` function gets called with the parameter 3. For this, I'm trying

```
connect(_button3, SIGNAL(clicked()), _fieldGrid, SLOT(resizeGrid(3))); //this is line 21
```

but I get the runtime error 
`QObject::connect: No such slot FieldGridWidget::resizeGrid(3) in ../filename.cpp:21`

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I make it so if I press the button, `resizeGrid(3)` gets called? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signatures of signals and slots must match - if not fully, then at least partially.

For example, you can connect a `signal(int, float)` to a `slot(int)`, but you can't connect a `signal(void)` to a `slot(int)`.

It is "sort of possible" to specify a slot parameter in the connection syntax, providing you are using Qt 5:

```
connect(_button3, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){ _fieldGrid->resizeGrid(3); });
```

Of course, you could use the signal mapper in this particular case, but it is a rather clumsy solution - extra verbose and limited to only a single int, string, widget or `QObject` parameter. With lambdas those limitations do not apply.

Comment: I'm trying  this code:
`connect(_button3,  SIGNAL(clicked()), this, {_fieldGrid->resizeGrid(3) });`
but now I get another error: `/filename.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to 'MyMainClass::connect(QPushButton*&, const char*, MyMainClass* const, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
     connect(_button3,  SIGNAL(clicked()), this, { _fieldGrid->resizeGrid(3) });` 
Why is this?

Comment: Because your code is wrong, I have given you the correct code. Who gave you that code?

Comment: No one, but your code also gives an error: `filename.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to 'MyMainClass::connect(QPushButton*&, void (QAbstractButton::*)(bool), MyMainClass::MyMainClass(QWidget*)::__lambda0)'
     connect(_button3, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){ _fieldGrid->resizeGrid(3); });`

Comment: @lte__ - that code works. It requires at least Qt version 5 and a C++11 compiler. You also need a `CONFIG += c++11` in your PRO file to use C++11 features. What is your Qt version and compiler?

Comment: In the .pro file I see Desktop Qt 5.5.1 GCC 64bit, and I also have C++11. I cannot find the `CONFIG += c++11` in the pro file though. What do I do?

Comment: Just copy/paste it in the PRO file.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot pass a value to a slot in Qt directly, as in `SLOT(resizeGrid(3))`. The argument to `SLOT` should be just the signature of your method (`resizeGrid()`).

There are two ways how to add an argument to a slot. This question about [how to pass arguments to a slot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5153157/24587) shows some solutions, repeated here. (Go upvote them!)

### The modern way : Qt5 and C++11

Instead of connecting a slot, connect to functor, as described by [Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652/kuba-ober) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411267/24587):

```
connect(action1,  &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(1); });
connect(action5,  &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(5); });
connect(action10, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(10); });
connect(action25, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(25); });
connect(action50, &QAction::triggered, this, [this]{ onStepIncreased(50); });
```

### Old fashioned : QSignalMapper

You can use a [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qsignalmapper.html) to perform what you want, as described by [TonyK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428857/tonyk) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153522/24587):

```
QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;
connect (action1, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
connect (action5, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
connect (action10, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
connect (action25, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;
connect (action50, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT(map())) ;

signalMapper -> setMapping (action1, 1) ;
signalMapper -> setMapping (action5, 5) ;
signalMapper -> setMapping (action10, 10) ;
signalMapper -> setMapping (action25, 25) ;
signalMapper -> setMapping (action50, 50) ;

connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(resizeGrid(int))) ;
```

Comment: You should link to existing answers rather than duplicating them.

Answer (score 1):

`clicked()` and `resizeGrid()` signatures should be the same, so you can create function, for example, `resizeGridForButton()`, where `resizeGrid(3)` will be executed, or change `resizeGrid()` signature and transfer `int n = 3` into it.

And it's <del>not</del> possible (example in the answer of *vsimkus*) to send params in `connect(...)`. Also you can send them in `emit` part through signal params.

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) is a good article about slots and signals.

Comment: "And it's not possible to send params in connect(...)" - yes it is possible.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, my fail.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, it has only been possible for a little over 3 years now ;)

Comment: @Anton So, if it is possible to pass the parameters, could you show me how to implement the code in my case? Thank you!

Comment: @lte I think it has been show in the answer of vsimkus (=