# Qt connect to slot/function with args

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new in Qt... I'm creating N buttons based on a JSON file. And I need to run a function/slot when a button is clicked and I need to know which buttton was pressed.
I tried:

```
QObject::connect(button, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &base::show_brands(json, type));
```

show_brands(json, type) is a function/slot...
but I can't send args like this... 
How can I sent args to my function/slot? Or how can I run a function when a button is clicked?

Comment: 1) to pass arguments into a slot you have to pass them through your signal.

2) or see this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153157/passing-an-argument-to-a-slot)

Comment: I tried signals but it's not working... Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I've searched online and I can check the sender... How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use QSignalMapper;

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html#details

This lets you send signals from a collection of objects to a single method which can identify the source object.

Comment: I tried signals but it's not working... Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I've searched online and I can check the sender... How do I do it?

Comment: it's working now...

Comment: connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(button, new_type);
    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SLOT(show_brands(QString))) ;