# QT extend MainWindow to other class or diffrent way

Tags: c++, qt

I have class `printrectangle`

```
class PrintRectangle : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PrintRectangle(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    void resetClickedIndex();
    void updateIndexFromPoint( const QPoint& point);
public:
    int mXIndex;
    int mYIndex;
    QVector<QPoint> points;
    bool clicked[5][5] = {};
    teacher tech;
    perceptron p[5][5];
    double techconst = 0.1;

signals:

public slots:
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *eventPress);
};
```

and `MainWindow`

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_learn_clicked();
    void on_classify_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

When I click button I call to `on_learn_clicked()` function. I would like to transfer `clicked[5][5]` array into `on_learn_clicked` becasue I send this array to other object when user click button. How to do this?

Comment: see this post on how to add parameter to a slot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153157/passing-an-argument-to-a-slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what is exactly the relation between MainWindow and the PrintRectangle widget. I suppose the button signal and PrintRectangle slot are connected somewhere in the MainWindow implementation.

One way to solve the problem would be to use to use the QSignalMapper as @Noidea stated.

Another way would be to use a lambda as a slot when connecting. This way you could capture the sender/receiver or other objects in scope and use their members.

You can find some information about the connect syntax in [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

But basically you could write something like:

```
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this, printRectangle]()
{
    // do smth with clicked[5][5] from printRectangle or just
    // retrieve it and call another method like:
    // this->processClicked(printRectangle->clicked);
    // or pass it to another object
}
```

This way you could modify your on_classify_clicked slot to a regular method with bool[5][5] argument to do the processing.