# Signaling a sliderReleased() with the new signal/slots implementation of Qt5

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5

I'm working with an example based on the following link

[Passing an argument to a slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153157/passing-an-argument-to-a-slot)

I'm trying to connect a certain function with a given parameter when a certain slider is released.

```
connect(m_customUIForm.horizontalSliderOr, &QAbstractSlider::sliderReleased(), this, [this]{ sendMoveActuator(1); });
```

The problem seems to lie in the signal `&QAbstractSlider::sliderReleased()`

```
error: cannot call member function 'void QAbstractSlider::sliderReleased()' without object
 connect(m_customUIForm.horizontalSliderOr, &QAbstractSlider::sliderReleased(), this, [this]{ sendMoveActuator(1); });
```

Which is the proper way to pass the signal of sliderReleased() ?

```
                                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples in the linked post, I suggest you remove the parentheses. I.e. not:

```
connect(m_customUIForm.horizontalSliderOr, &QAbstractSlider::sliderReleased(), this, [this]{ sendMoveActuator(1); });
```

But rather:

```
connect(m_customUIForm.horizontalSliderOr, &QAbstractSlider::sliderReleased, this, [this]{ sendMoveActuator(1); });
```